# In pandas-python or tabulate: how to set FIXED column width?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, file-writing

I am creating dataframes with pandas and then writing them into .txt-files with the tabulate package. But I need the columns of the .txt-tables to have **exactly** 11 characters width (I need to do this, because the .txt are later read by a fortran program that reads only fixed width columns). I find no option in the pandas or tabulate packages to set the width of the table columns. I read about `pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth',100)` but this sets only a **maximum width**, not a **fixed width**, and it is for the **display**, not for the **writing** into files.

Anybody knows an option for setting the width? Or maybe an alternative package to tabulate, that allows this?

---

**SOLUTION DUE TO INSTRUCTIONS IN @zipa's ANSWER:**

Output is now indeed in columns of width=11 characters, but in the 5th column from the right one sees that this gets disrupted - because floats <10e+11 get represented in decimal notation, not in exponential/scientific. This is caused by str(x)

seen here, check 5th column from right:

```
C_2_       ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        , C         , C         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,2.49e-08   ,0.0        ,71600      ,2          ,100        ,6.01e+11   ,-1.0       ,71600      ,2          ,100        
CH         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        , C         , H         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,3.16e-10   ,0.0        ,33700      ,2          ,100        ,7630000000.0,-1.0       ,33700      ,2          ,100        
CN         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        , C         , N         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,1e-09      ,0.0        ,71000      ,2          ,100        ,24200000000.0,0.0        ,71000      ,2          ,100        
CO         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        , C         , O         ,nan        ,nan        ,nan        ,0.000152   ,-3.1       ,12900      ,2          ,100        ,3.67e+15   ,-4.1       ,12900      ,2          ,100
```

For solving this issue first I turned the "nan" into balnk space:
 `df.fillna(' ',inplace=True)`. Next I followed @zipa's later comment and changed the one line of his suggested code - I made the lambda function take and if-clause and have different behavior depending if the entry is string or float:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).ljust(11) if type(x)==str else str('{:.3e}'.format(x)).ljust(11))
```

**And this solved my problem!** - see output below:

```
C2         ,           ,           ,           ,           , C         , C         ,           ,           ,           ,2.490e-08  ,0.000e+00  ,7.160e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  ,6.010e+11  ,-1.000e+00 ,7.160e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  
CH         ,           ,           ,           ,           , C         , H         ,           ,           ,           ,3.160e-10  ,0.000e+00  ,3.370e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  ,7.630e+09  ,-1.000e+00 ,3.370e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  
CN         ,           ,           ,           ,           , C         , N         ,           ,           ,           ,1.000e-09  ,0.000e+00  ,7.100e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  ,2.420e+10  ,0.000e+00  ,7.100e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  
CO         ,           ,           ,           ,           , C         , O         ,           ,           ,           ,1.520e-04  ,-3.100e+00 ,1.290e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02  ,3.670e+15  ,-4.100e+00 ,1.290e+04  ,2.000e+00  ,1.000e+02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, could this be what you need, it turns everything into 11 characters long text:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12345, 2, 3], 'b': list('ABC')})
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).ljust(11))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: str(x).ljust(11))
df.to_csv('somefile.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: It does the job, as long the initial values in the columns are strings. But some values are large floats. And then your solution makes all the floats < 1.0e+11 to be expressed as decimals. For example 7.63e+09 is getting expressed as 7630000000.0 and this goes over the column width extent and destroys the alignment. I think the reason for that is turning the entries to strings with str(x). Can we do the mapping you suggest and still use **floats**? Or maybe convert to floats before writing to file?

Comment: If your whole column is float, can you cast that column like `'{:.2e}'.format(7630000000.0)`?

Comment: I guess this would be a solution, but it would take a lot of coding to implement it on the whole dataframe with about a dozen columns, half of them with floats, half with strings. I am looking for an easier/shorter way

Comment: I can't code at the moment but just checking: would column type determination be of any use? If so, please share example of data and I'll write up solution tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks, zapa :) ! I have edited my initial question, so it contains example output data. I guess you can use it as example input data to, just read it with pd.read_csv, this is what I am doing for my task